# value of k in KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, knn

I am trying to find best `K` value for `KNeighborsClassifier`.

This is my code for `iris` dataset:

```
k_loop = np.arange(1,30)
k_scores = []
for k in k_loop:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    cross_val = cross_val_score(knn, X, y, cv=10 , scoring='accuracy')
    k_scores.append(cross_val.mean())
```

I have taken mean of cross_val_score in each loop and plotted it.

```
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.plot(k_loop, k_scores)
plt.show()
```

This is the result.

[image: Line Plot]

You can see the accuracy is higher when `k` is between `14` to `20`.

1) How can I choose the best value of k.

2) Are there any other ways to calculate and find best value for `K`?

3) Any other improvement suggestions are also appreciated. I'm new to `ML`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first define what is `K`?

`K` is the number of ***voters*** that the algorithm consult to make a decision about *to which class a given data point it belongs to*.

In other words, it uses `K` to make boundaries of each class. These boundaries will segregate each class from the other.

Accordingly, the boundary becomes smoother with increasing value of `K`.

So logically speaking, if we increase `K` to ***infinity***, it will finally become all points of any class depending on the ***total majority***!. However, that would lead to what is called **High Bias** (i.e. Underfitting).

In contrast, if we make `K` equals only **1**, then the error will always be **zero** for the ***training sample***. This is because the closest point to any training data point is itself. Nevertheless, we will end up ***overfitting*** the boundaries (i.e. High Variance), so it **cannot generalize** for any new and unseen data!.

Unfortunately, there is **no** rule of thumb. Choice of `K` is somewhat driven by the end application as well as the dataset.

---

### Suggested Solution

Using [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) which performs *exhaustive search over specified parameter values for an estimator.* So we use it to try find best value of `K`.

For me, I don't exceed the max class with respect to the number of elements in each class when I want to set the max threshold of `K`, and it hasn't let me down so far (*see the example later to see what I am talking about*)

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
# get the max class with respect to the number of elements
max_class = np.max(np.bincount(y))
# you can add other parameters after doing your homework research
# for example, you can add 'algorithm' : ['auto', 'ball_tree', 'kd_tree', 'brute']
grid_param = {'n_neighbors': range(1, max_class)}
model = KNeighborsClassifier()
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=2)
clf = GridSearchCV(model, grid_param, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy')
clf.fit(X, y)
print("Best Estimator: \n{}\n".format(clf.best_estimator_))
print("Best Parameters: \n{}\n".format(clf.best_params_))
print("Best Score: \n{}\n".format(clf.best_score_))
```

**Result**

```
Best Estimator: 
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=17, p=2,
           weights='uniform')

Best Parameters: 
{'n_neighbors': 17}

Best Score: 
0.98
```

---

**An Update Regarding `RepeatedStratifiedKFold`**

In simple words, it's a `KFold` that is **repeated** over `n_repeats` of times, *Why*? Because it may lower bias and give you a better estimate in terms of statistics.

Also it's `Stratified` that is it seeks to ensure that each class is *approximately* equally represented across each test fold (i.e. *each fold is representative of **all** strata of the data*).

Comment: Thank you. It helps a lot. Just one doubt I haven't came accros `RepeatedStratisfiedKFold`. Can you explain it a bit in the answer on what it does. I always used `cv=10` in `GridSearchCV`? why should I use `cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=2)` rather than cv=10? any advantages?

Comment: @user2475 I updated my answer and added the motivation for using `RepeatedStratisfiedKFold` in Classification Problems.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the graph, I would say 13.

I assume this is a classification job.
in that case: **Do not** set k to be an even number.

E.g. If you have 2 class A and B, and k is set to 4.
There is a possibility that the new data (or point)
is between 2 class A and 2 class B.
So you will have 2 voting to classify the new data point as A
 and 2 voting to classify as B.
Setting k to be an odd number avoid this situation.

Comment: It's not clear. Can you explain a bit more with an example? Why is even number is not good?

Comment: Imagine a 2 cm by 2 cm square.   In this square there's many points which are classified either as class A or B.  And you have a new point with the coordinate (1, 1) and want to classify it.  "KNeighborsClassier" will find "k" neighbors that are nearest to this new point and have them "vote" to classify under which label.   If you set "k" to be 6, 6 points nearest to (1,1) will be used.  There is a chance that 3 of them are class A and  3 are class B.  In that case, what should this point be classified as?   Setting "k" do be an odd number avoids this situation.